# Find a point in a multipolygon geometry

Tags: postgis, point, point-in-polygon, st-intersects

I need to know which points from Table 1 are contained in Table 2.

In Table 1 I have longitude and latitude and I made points with `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(d.longitude, d.latitude),4326) as geom`

Table 2 has a collection of multipolygons: geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)

I know it is a collection because when I run
`select ST_IsCollection(geom)from table2` it is TRUE, but when I want to know how many collections with `SELECT ST_NumGeometries(geom)from table 2`, it returns 1.

I know that since I have a collection I have to use st_INTERSECTS.

```
select TABLE1.*, TABLE2.*
from TABLE1, TABLE2
where ST_Intersects(TABLE2.geom, TABLE1.geom)
```

But it is empty. And I know from plotting the data that they intersect.

Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: you are missing aliases, e.g. `TABLE1 AS T1`, `TABLE2 AS T2`

Comment: Yes @BERA is postgis

Comment: you're title is misleading -- its a multipolygon collection. If I were you I would dump the collection into an actual geometry. I think postgis recently allowed collections to be used in spatial functions such as st_intersects but that depends on what version of postgis you have

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at St_Dump: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html and [Using multipolygon or polygon features for large intersect operations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/101425/7849)

Assuming that Table2 are the polygons, this would be:

```
select T1.*, T2.*
from TABLE1 as T1, TABLE2 as T2
where ST_Intersects(St_Dump(T2.geom), T1.geom)
```

Comment: No Pieter, thanks, but that is not the problem. I edited the question, I wrote T1 T2 for convenience.